# Conditionally add a css class in views, not using erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible, and if so, is it suggested?

I want to add a class to an element if a condition is true. The only way I can figure out how to do this is using erb in the view itself using something like:

```
<div <%= if @status == 'success'; "class='do-something'"; end %>>
   message
</div>
```

or using `div_for` but it's messy and I'd much rather set the class of an html element using a helper or methods in the model/controller itself. something like:

If action succeeds, find the html element somehow (by data attribute, by class, etc) and add a class to it.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with Javascript?

Comment: Yeah that's certainly an option, was just thinking there must be a rails way to do it instead of cluttering up my views.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways to do what you want. Here's one:

```
<%= content_tag :div, message, class: ("do-something" if @status == "success") %>
```

If you want to make it a helper, that's easy too:

```
def message(status, message=nil, &block)
  css_class = "do-something" if @status == success
  if block
    content_tag(:div, class: css_class, &block)
  else
    content_tag(:div, message, class: css_class)
  end
end
```

Then:

```
<%= message @status do -%>
  Message
<% end %>
```

Or:

```
<%= message @status, "Message" %>
```

Comment: Dear downvoter: Please leave a comment explaining the reason for your downvote. If my answer is lacking I would appreciate the opportunity to improve it.

Comment: The `message` helper in my answer doesn't use ERB, and OP wrote "I'd much rather set the class of an html element *using a helper*…", so I'd say my answer pretty directly addresses what was asked.

Comment: Sure, your solution looks like it uses ERB to me, so as far as I can tell it doesn't address the question that was asked.  Presumably, the op doesn't want to have to search through the view and insert some ERB everywhere the class might need changing, as well as have to remember to insert ERB in any future additions to the view.  If I misinterpreted your code, please let me know, and I'll change my downvote.

Comment: Now, you've used selected quoting, and I would double downvote your answer for sheer dishonesty.  You sort of forgot this part of the quote: *in the model/controller itself.*  You've used ERB to answer the question--it doesn't matter if you shuttled most of the code into a helper.  It's ERB all the way down.

Comment: OP wrote "using a helper *or* methods in the model/controller…" This kind of logic does not go in the model or controller, so I chose to write a helper, which is one of the options OP specifically mentioned. I'm sorry omitting the part after the conjunction upset you so much.

Comment: Alright, I can see your interpretation of the text.  Please edit your post and I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

> Conditionally add a css class in views, not using erb?

You can parse your view with Nokogiri, then modify the html:

```
  def some_action
    status = 'success'
    @planet = 'mars' #ERB variable

    if status == 'success'
      html = render_to_string  #The view after executing the ERB 
                               #and applying the ERB variables and
                               #adding the layout.

      doc = Nokogiri::HTML html
      target_class = 'title'

      tags_containing_target_class = doc.xpath(
        "//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' #{target_class} ')]"
      )  #A well known method to search a class like class="title   bold"
         #or class="bold   title"

      class_to_add = 'highlight'

      tags_containing_target_class.each do |tag|
        tag['class'] = tag['class'] << " #{class_to_add}"
      end

      render text: doc.to_html
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
 <div class=<%= @status == 'success' ? 'do-something' : '' %>>
 </div>
```